# Vertical text alignment page after page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am using this template to write my thesis:

https://www.overleaf.com/5578703kpqfrz#/17992947/

I noticed, and I really don't know know how to solve this, that the text is not aligned when I scroll the pages. You can notice the same from page 1 on (almost at the bottom of the document) that the text is aligned in a certain way, and at the next page it's aligned more on the left.. and so on alternating each other, page after page. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is the norm for two sided printing: the inner margin is always smaller than the outer one. The reason for this is that, when you open a book, you see *two* inner margins next to each other (from the left page and from the right page).

Comment: Now it's clear.. I am not sure whether this is a nice thing to do if I am not going to print my thesis but only present it online. This is something I will try to find out but, in case I don't want that, what should I modify?

Comment: In the template, replace`\geometry{…, inner=2.5cm, outer=3.8cm, bindingoffset=2cm,…}`  with, say, `\geometry{…, hmargin=3.5cm,…}`. This way, both margins will be 3.5cm and text width will be 14cm.